# Проблема с установкой Visual Studio 2010 на Windows XP

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

Проблема с установкой Visual Studio 2010 на Windows XP. Подскажите, что делать. Так же хотелось бы уточнить возможна ли установка Visual Studio 2010 на Windows XP.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

VS 2010 официально поддерживает работу в WinXP (Windows XP (x86) с пакетом обновления 3 (SP3) - все выпуски, кроме Starter)

Описание совместимостей и известных проблем: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=133421

Также может возникнуть необходимость отключить DEP в файле boot.ini и перезагрузиться:

> [boot loader]
>   timeout=30
>   default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
>
> [operating systems]
>   multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS=”Microsoft Windows XP Professional” /fastdetect /NoExecute=AlwaysOff

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psiman/2010/03/02/installing-visual-studio-2010-rc1-on-xp-sp3/

Answer (score -1):

Скачай iso-образ с оффлайновым инсталлятором.